# can i try windows azure free trial without having a credit card?

Tags: trial

Am trying to make a free account of Windows Azure to discover it, i have provided the verification code, and passed, but it then asked for a credit card number. is that really important.. isn`t that the "3 months free" account, why the credit card needed?
and if it was, what are my other options if am not having such credit card?

Answer (score 23):

I would add more info to having Windows Azure Trial subscription:

1. Yes you need a Windows Live account and Credit to verify your Identity only.
2. You will not be charged to your Credit Card for this trial account as long as you have set your account under spending limit.
3. Windows Azure Trial account is set to cost ZERO and that is assured by not letting your cross the account usage limit by setting the spending limit enabled. Spending limits are described here:
   https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/
4. Having spending limit enabled means, if you exceed your limited resources quota your account will be disabled for that month because resources are provided monthly basis.
5. At the end of your trial or during the trial period you have ability to move to regular subscription and then your credit card will be charged for regular subscription account.
6. IF you decided to get regular Windows Azure account you will be given a new When new subscription which will incur charges as your usage

So the bottom line is yes you need Credit card to provide the proof of your identity however while using your Windows Azure Trial account you will not be charged at all. Once you setup your Spending Limit so you can sleep tension free in night for any charges to your credit card.

Comment: Oh. That's not good. :(

Comment: Have anyone really made it with 0 cost on the card ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can't. Charges still apply if you exceed the free quota provided to you in Trial period.

Comment: i`ll make a one after i finish my quota :D

Comment: Associating a credit card to your account means, you have the ability to pay the bill.

Comment: It is guaranteed that trial account will not cost at all. Your account will be disabled for the month if you exceed the quota in that month.